# Changing keystore on wso2is

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to change the wso2carbon.jks keystore used by default by wso2is (4.6).

I've followed the procedure described in http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2011/08/adding-ca-certificate-authority-signed-certificate-wso2-products/

I've updated the conf/carbon.xml with the right passwd as below

```
<KeyStore>
    <Location>repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
    ......
</KeyStore>

<RegistryKeyStore>
  <Location>repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
  ....
</RegistryKeyStore>
```

but I still arrive to the following error.

I've also tried to change the conf/axis2/axis2.conf

```
 <transportReceiver name="https"   class="org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOSSLListener">
 244         <parameter name="port" locked="false">8243</parameter>
245         <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
246         <parameter name="keystore" locked="false">
247             <KeyStore>
248                 <Location>repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
249                 <Type>JKS</Type>
250                 <Password>wso2carbonpwd</Password>
251                 <KeyPassword>mypasswd</KeyPassword>
252             </KeyStore>
255
 <transportSender name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOSSLSender">
416         <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
417         <parameter name="keystore" locked="false">
418             <KeyStore>
419                 <Location>repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
420                 <Type>JKS</Type>
421                 <Password>wso2carbonpwd</Password>
422                 <KeyPassword>mypasswd</KeyPassword>
423             </KeyStore>
424         </parameter>
425
```

But I still have this error .....

Could someone help me

```
TID: [0] [IS] [2014-04-08 10:06:56,416]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  : https://system.x.y.z:9443/carbon/ {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent}
TID: [0] [IS] [2014-04-08 10:06:56,512] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.internal.EntitlementServiceComponent} -  Error in initializing thrift transport {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.internal.EntitlementServiceComponent}
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Error creating the transport
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createSSLContext(TSSLTransportFactory.java:201)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getServerSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:102)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.internal.EntitlementServiceComponent.startThriftEntitlementService(EntitlementServiceComponent.java:328)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.internal.EntitlementServiceComponent.startThriftServices(EntitlementServiceComponent.java:299)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.internal.EntitlementServiceComponent.activate(EntitlementServiceComponent.java:161)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Comment: You also need to modify the certificate details in repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml if you need to change the certificate of default http/s transports

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you want to update the keystore details,  that can be found in `identity.xml` file at /repository/conf directory.

```
<Location>${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can learn how to do this by following this [blog post](http://sencs.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-change-default-keystores-and.html).